# how to validate token in jwt authentication in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-middleware

how to validate the JWT token in `Simple JWT` authentication. I need to verify when the user sends a request if the token access token is expired so it will redirect him to refresh the token.

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        # The default result (access/refresh tokens)
        data = super(CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        # Custom data you want to include
        data.update({'email': self.user.email})
        data.update({'id': self.user.id})
        data.update({'status':"success"})
        # and everything else you want to send in the response
        return data
```

**views.py**

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    # Replace the serializer with your custom
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView

urlpatterns = [
  
  
    path('token/', views.CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what problem you have? Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: I need to liké add a middleware to a simple jwt authentication , so for the first Time thé user login in je recieves an Access Token and a refreshet Token, and when je triés to for example add a New post , he sends thé Access Token in thé request, i need to first verify if thé Token is not expired, if it is expired then i redirect him to thé refresh Token endpoint otherwise , hé Can add the post , and i need to do it with http only cookies in simple jwt , i searchef a lot but i dont know if i Can Do it with this library

Answer (score 0):

You must add jwt authentication middleware in your settings.py authentication class for rest framework.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
         ...
)
```